# cProfile not showing any (real) results--all 000's--in Python

Tags: python-3.x, profiling, cprofile

In running cProfile on anything (for example a mergeSort) I'm getting all 000's in the runtimes, and key lines/vars/methods not listed/tested in the process.  Only seems to test under methods, internals.  Please advise.

below are my results for a mergeSort, I've tried running the
python -m cProfile [mergeSort(lst)] w/ and w/out brackets--saw both in documentation.
Only version I can get to work is the:
import cProfile
cProfile.run(mergeSort(lst))

or the enable() disable() method shown.

formatting doesn't turn out well, so attached image.
[cProfile Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQDWq.png)

results:

'''
[17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]
         127 function calls (111 primitive calls) in 0.000 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     17/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :1(mergeSort)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :36()
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :37()
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codeop.py:132(**call**)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hooks.py:142(**call**)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hooks.py:207(pre_run_code_hook)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 interactiveshell.py:1104(user_global_ns)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 interactiveshell.py:2933(run_code)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ipstruct.py:125(**getattr**)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.compile}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
       91    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

'''

Comment: maybe your code runs too fast. Try to repeat it in a loop

Comment: please no code as images, and from the input data which has less than 10 elements, no wonder why you get only zeroes; Try to create a much bigger list.